# Getting "bad-precaching-response " error after service worker registeration is successful

Tags: service-worker, next.js, koa

In my project, I am using NextJS+KOA+Apollo. My nextJS app is inside client in root directory. I am using next-offline to convert it to PWA.

Nextjs app is inside client directory. koa server is inside server directory.

when i am building the app via below command:

```
next build client && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json
```

it creates a build directory inside client for nextjs and dist directory at the top level for koa server.

i run the code in production via below command

```
NODE_ENV=production node dist/server/index.js
```

ISSUE
Service worker is getting registered properly. But I am getting below error:

```
PrecacheController.mjs:194 
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://my-domain/_next/bo.svg?__WB_REVISION__=e02afe0476bb357aebde18136fda06e0","status":404}] 
at l.o (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1749) 
at async Promise.all (index 0) 
at async l.install (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1221)
```

[image]

Below is my build file that gets generated:

[image]

tsconfig.server.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2017",
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Below is my next.config.js (inside client direcotry)

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const offline = require("next-offline");
const pino = require("next-pino");
const withTypescript = require("@zeit/next-typescript");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");
const _ = require("lodash");

const nextConfig = {
  distDir: "build",
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    });
    config.plugins.push(
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), ".env"),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
    );
    return config;
  },
  // overwrites values given in the .env file with the current
  // process.env value
  env: _.omitBy(
    {
      GRAPHQL_SERVER: process.env.GRAPHQL_SERVER,
    },
    _.isUndefined,
  ),
  workboxOpts: {
    globPatterns: ["static/**/*"],
    globDirectory: "client",
    runtimeCaching: [
      {
        urlPattern: /^https?.*/,
        handler: "NetworkFirst",
        options: {
          cacheName: "offlineCache",
          expiration: {
            maxEntries: 200,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};

const cssConfig = {
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]",
  },
};

const lessConfig = cssConfig;

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [offline],
    [pino],
    [withTypescript],
    [withCSS, cssConfig],
    [withLess, lessConfig],
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

And below is my file to start koa server

```
import Router from "koa-router";
 const server = new Koa();
const dev = !["production", "staging"].includes(process.env.NODE_ENV || "");
const app = next({ dir: "./client", dev });
const publicRouter = new Router();

const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

publicRouter.get("/service-worker.js", async ctx => {
      const pathname = await join(
        __dirname,
        "../../../client/build",
        "service-worker.js",
      );
      ctx.body = await app.serveStatic(ctx.req, ctx.res, pathname);
      ctx.respond = false;
    });

publicRouter.get("*", async ctx => {
      if (!ctx.path.match(/graphql/)) {
        await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
        ctx.respond = false;
      }
    });

server.use(async (ctx, next) => {
      ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
      await next();
    });
server.use(publicRouter.routes()).use(publicRouter.allowedMethods());
 server.listen({ port: 3000 });
```

================================================================

I have done a dirty fix for now. I am not sure how to handle it properly. I will really appreciate if anyone can put forth their view on this.

As bo.svg, firfox.svg, all these static files are throwing 404,
Ex - (/_next/bo.svg?WB_REVISION=e02afe0476bb357aebde18136fda06e0)
in my file to start koa server, added a condition to check this URL and serve static file from build directory like below:

```
publicRouter.get("*", async ctx => {
      if (ctx.path.match(/\_next/) && ctx.path.match(/\.svg/)) {
        const pathname = await join(
          __dirname,
          "../../../client/build",
          ctx.path.replace("_next/", ""),
        );
        ctx.body = await app.serveStatic(ctx.req, ctx.res, pathname);
        ctx.respond = false;
      } else if (!ctx.path.match(/graphql/)) {
        await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
        ctx.respond = false;
      }
    });
```

It served my prupose for now, but not sure how to handle this properly.